# How do I limit the amount of sql responses when multiple rows in my table have the same value?

Tags: mysql

If my table looks like this

```
id -  car  - color
1  -  BMW  - red
2  -  JAG  - blue
3  -  JEEP - pink
4  -  MERC - blue
5  -  BMW  - black
6  -  BMW  - black
7  -  BMW  - black
8  -  BMW  - black
9  -  BMW  - black
10 -  JEEP - pink
11 -  JEEP - pink
12 -  JEEP - pink
13 -  JEEP - pink
14 -  JAG  - blue
15 -  JAG  - blue
16 -  JAG  - blue
17 -  JAG  - blue
18 -  MERC - blue
19 -  MERC - blue
```

What query should I write so my response is `[bmw, Jag, jeep, Merc]` Meaning that only one of them gets picked?

I tried something like

```sql
SELECT * FROM entries WHERE client UNIQUE
```

but I know that it's super wrong

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT car FROM entries`

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the SELECT DISTINCT statement.  The SELECT DISTINCT statement is used to return only distinct (different) values. Read more about SELECT DISTINCT [here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp).

```
SELECT DISTINCT car FROM entries;
```

UNIQUE is a constraint used while creating schemas. You can read more about UNIQUE [here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_unique.asp)

[Read more here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp)